# iPhone 6: How to interrupt software updates that continue to use mobile data?

Tags: software-update, cellular-data, iphone

[image: System Services Screenshot]

How to turn off software updates?

[image: iTunes & App Store Settings]

[image: Cellular Settings]

iPhone 6, iOS 8.1.1. Everything seems to be turned off, still software updates is using the greatest amount of cell data. By resetting the stats we still see data being used.

Answer (score 1):

Fischer, there are two different types of software updates that occur on iOS; updates to the apps you have installed and updates to the operating system itself.

To disable app updates over your friend’s cellular connection, navigate to Settings → iTunes & App Store and scroll to the very bottom. Tap the toggle next to “Use Cellular Data,” but keep in mind that this will also disable the use of iTunes Match and iTunes Radio over the phone’s cellular connection.

If you are concerned about updates to iOS itself being installed over your friend’s cellular connection, don’t be — having contacted a friend of mine who is an Apple Genius, she tells me that your iPhone won’t install updates to your operating system without a connection to WiFi or the user’s specific permission.

If your friend continues to have an issue, she may want to contact Apple about a potential bug.

Comment: Per the user's screenshot, the setting you mention is already disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, once the updates start, you don't have a good way to end them other than letting the download complete. You could turn off cellular data entirely or connect to WiFi for the download.

You could also erase all content and settings and then restore from a backup - but that's quite a lot of work to kill one download that'a already started.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to go to settings>Cellular. Then you should see a list of apps with a toggle button next to each one. Scroll down until you find the "Settings" icon. You want to turn the switch off. This will deny the settings application (which is what gets software updates) the ability to use cellular data.

Hope this helped

Comment: even that is turned off, question updated to show a screenshot of that

Comment: Did you reset the usage statistics? Perhaps the large amount of data you see has just been an accumulation of the data usage since the stats were last reset.

Comment: yes my friend did reset it, and he's been having the issue for sometime now, not new

Comment: Im sorry I am at a loss. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Background App Refresh.
Apple now allows apps to automatically update and download content in the background. This feature can harm battery life and cause apps to use cellular data, even while you’re not using them. Disable background app refresh and an app will only use data when you open it, not in the background.

To access these options, open the Settings app, tap General, and tap Background App Refresh. Toggle apps to off if you don’t want them to refresh in the background, or disable the background app refresh feature for every app on your phone.

Disabling push notifications can also save a bit of data, although push notifications are rather tiny.

Reference: http://www.howtogeek.com/212295/how-to%C2%A0reduce-your-iphone%E2%80%99s-cellular-data-usage/

Answer (score 0):

Go to General / usage / Manage storage / scroll down to IOS icon and tap it: you then get an option to delete the download.